# Magento: How to add promo code form on one page checkout page?

Tags: magento-1.8

I want to add a promo code form programmatically on one page checkout page of Magento 1.8 CE. This has to be added under payment review section.

Added following snippet to `layout/checkout.xml` of active theme:

```
<block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>
```

then added following php code to `template/checkout/onepage.phtml`

But its not working, please help!

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?>
```

Comment: Where do you want it to be displayed? Means Billing,shipping,Overview?

Comment: Did you refresh the cache or flush ?

Comment: @Dario, yes I did refresh cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `checkout.xml` layout file add as following,

```
<block type="checkout/onepage_review_info" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml">    
...    
    <block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>    
...    
</block>
```

And put the following code in `app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?>
```

Comment: I also need to add javascript "
 window.discountForm = new VarienForm('discount-coupon-form');" for it to work

Comment: where you have added this javascript ?

Comment: Not working, after adding your code onepage checkout page error, could you pls explain briefly how can i add?